# Remove header image in NSIS installer

Tags: nsis

I understand that NSIS uses the installer icon (or `MUI_ICON`) as the header image by default. And that using `MUI_HEADERIMAGE` without specifying `MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP` uses the default `Contrib\Graphics\Header\nsis.bmp`

But is it possible to not display a header image altogether? (Aside from the option of specifying a blank (all-white) image as `MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT HideHeaderImage
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function HideHeaderImage
!if "${MUI_SYSVERSION}" >= 2.0
  ShowWindow $mui.Header.Image 0
!else
  GetDlgItem $0 $hwndParent 0x416
  ShowWindow $0 0
!endif
FunctionEnd
```

Alternatively you could edit one of the UIs in ${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UIs\modern*.exe with [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to move the image control offscreen and then use MUI_UI or MUI_UI_HEADERIMAGE in your script to select your new UI file.

Answer (score -1):

Can you show what function HideHeaderImage would look like for

!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "leftside.bmp"

Comment: This is not an answer, better insert it into a comment